# cancancanで権限毎にControllerのロジックを変えたい(current_userの場合とadminの場合)のですが、if文が多くなり困っております。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

cancancanのgemを用いて権限管理を前提としたサービスを開発しております。

仮に以下のロールがあったとします。

admin_user
hoge_user
piyo_user

これらのユーザーで

admin_userはすべての情報を知ることができ、
それ以外のユーザーはcurrent_userに関連する情報のみ見ることができる

といった機能を開発したいです。

こういう場合に
私の理解では、Controllerにその処理を書くには

```
if current_user.admin?
  Article.all
else
  current_user.articles
end
```

といった処理になるかと思います。

これはこれでいいのかもしれませんが、
今回、権限毎で処理を変えたいControllerが多数あり、
if文を量産してしまうことになります。

そのため、
cancancanやその他gemなどを用いて、
そこの処理を完結にまとめられないかなと考えております。

cancancanのAbilityクラスなどはまさにそういったことができるのかなと思ったのですが、

あくまで

can
cannot

の振り分けしかできないのかなというのが私の理解です。

皆さんならこういう用件に対して、どのようにアプローチするのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/36510 こちらにも別の方が回答を書いています。回答者の時間の無駄ですから、せめて質問同士リンクを貼るくらいの配慮はしてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) だと明示的に書くことができますね。

下記のようにポリシーファイルを書いて、

```
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        user.articles
        # または、 
        # scope.where(user_id: user.id)
      end
    end
  end   
end
```

controller では、次のように使います。

```
def index
  @articles = policy_scope(Article)
end
```

ポリシーファイルの`scope`には、`Article`が渡ります。

cancancan は詳しくないのですが、`load_resource` が似たような仕組みなのではないでしょうか？

ポリシーファイルで、admin 以外に対する where 条件を付記し、

```
if user.admin?
  can :index, Article
else
  can :index, Article, user_id: user.id
end
```

controller で、`load_resouce` を書くと、自動的に @articles に読み込まれる

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   load_resource

   def index
     @articles # <- 自動的に @articles が定義される。
   end
```

のではないかと思います。

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#load_resource
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。詳細に解説なさって頂けたおかげで、理解することができました。危うく、controller内が条件分岐だらけになりそうだったので大変感謝しております。

こちらをもとに、開発を続けていたのですが、権限周りで表題とは別の問題が生じました。

もしこちらについても、宜しければ、ご助言頂けますと幸いです。
質問ばかりで大変恐縮ではありますが、よろしくお願いします。

http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/25361/cancancan%E3%81%AEgem%E3%81%A7dashboardcontroller%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AAcontroller%E3%81%A8abillity%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E8%B1%A1%E3%81%8C%E9%81%95%E3%81%86%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9A-uninit

Comment: また、仰るとおり、load_resourceが今回の表題の問題を解消する鍵となってました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: お役に立てて良かったです！もし解決されたとお考えの場合は、解決済みにマークをされると、他の閲覧者の助けになりますので、ご検討ください。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: 解消済みマークを付けました！この度はありがとうございます。