# cancancanのgemでDashboardControllerのようなControllerとAbillityの対象が違うケースにおいて機能せず、uninitialized constant Dashboardとなります。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

DashboardController内で、Userの一覧などを表示させるようなケースにおいて、
uninitialized constant Dashboard
というエラーが表示されます。

ControllerとAbillityの対象とがちがっていてもcancancanを機能させたいのですが、
どのようにすればいいのかがわからず難航しております。

```
class DashboardController
  load_and_authorize_resource (1)
  #skip_load_and_authorize_resource (2)
  #load_and_authorize_resource :user, :parent => false (3)

  @users = current_user (4)

end
```

(1) これだと次のエラーが表示されます。
uninitialized constant Dashboard

(2) これだと、エラーはなくなるものの、権限管理ができてないので、目的にそえておりません。

(3) 調べているとこういうやり方でいけると書いてあったのですが、私の環境下では上手く行きませんでした。
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#custom-class

(4) Adminの場合はUser.allでほしく、それ以外の場合はcurrent_userを取得したい。

こちらのやり方は、権限チェックを自作なさっておりますが、
このやり方だと、(4)の部分が上手くいかず、こちらのやり方でも難航しております。
http://qiita.com/snaka/items/2f30e6abedf7f7a33e99

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

(3)の回答が役に立つと思います。今回は参照されたサイトの1番目をお使いでしたが、2番目のオプションをお試しください。

> If the model class is namespaced differently than the controller you will need to specify the :class option.

ざっと翻訳すると、

> もし controller と class の名前が異なるなら、 :class オプションを使う必要があります。

よって、`class` オプションの方を使って、下記のように書くことができると考えます。

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource class: "User"
end
```

## 2016-06-02 21:07 追記

試したところ、変数名に誤解がありましたので、追記します。

```
class DashboardController
  load_and_authorize_resource class: "User"

  def index   
    Rails.logger.debug @users              # => nil
    Rails.logger.debug @dashboards.to_sql  # => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  end  
end
```

参照しているクラス名ではなく、controller 名の変数名に格納されていました。
上記をコピーして、お試しになられると良いかもしれません。
(もしかして、`def index` が無かったりないでしょうか？)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
class オプションを用いてUserを呼びだそうとしましたがuninitialized constant Dashboardのままでした。
UserController等、色々と試したのですが、同様のエラーでした。

Comment: gemソース内？の
constant.const_get(name)のところでエラーがでているようです。

      names.inject(Object) do |constant, name|
        if constant == Object
          constant.const_get(name)
        else